# отличие require от require_relative

Tags: ruby

Дядьки бородачи, объясните в Ruby отличие require от require_relative.
Верной ли дорогой иду.

1. `require            # абсолютный путь к файлу.`
2. `require_relative   # относительный путь к файлу.`

Есть ли еще какие отличия.

Answer (score 10):

## Нет, неверной.

- `require` производит поиск в папках, указанных в `$LOAD_PATH` (это такая глобальная переменная в Ruby). По порядку, подставляет искомый путь к каждой записи из массива и пытается найти файл. Если нигде нет — `LoadError`.
- `require_relative` производит поиск от **текущей папки** (файл из которой на данный момент исполняется, видимый в константе `__FILE__`; не путайте с *рабочей папкой*, которую можно получить с помощью `File.expand_path "."`).

Абсолютные пути они воспринимают **обе и одинаково**.

---

Но с абсолютными путями подобные действия обычно не совершают. Во всяком случае из **файлов** с кодом (в противоположность REPL вроде `irb` или `pry`), т. к. интересующую папку с кодом можно добавить в `$LOAD_PATH` при старте и "реквайрить" файлы по пути от неё.

Например, в гипотетическом файле `/home/user/foo/run.rb` мог бы быть такой код:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.join(__dir__, "lib") # Добавить лежащую рядом с файлом папку `lib`

require "bar" # Будет последовательно искать `bar.rb` в каждой папке из `$LOAD_PATH`
              # Первая строчка требует посмотреть по пути `/home/user/foo/lib/bar.rb`
```

Отметьте, что если переместить папку `foo` целиком в другое место, загружаться при выполнении `run.rb` будет тот же файл. Чего не произошло бы, если бы в файле был зашит абсолютный путь.

---

#### Забавно, но...

`require`, которым обычно пользуются, не из Ruby, а [из RubyGems](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#requiring-code).  RubyGems добавляет поиск указанного гема и добавление папки с его кодом (обычно подпапка `lib` в геме) в `$LOAD_PATH`, после чего передаёт управление в обычный `require`.

RubyGems оставляет исходный `require` под именем `gem_original_require` (хотя это может быть деталь реализации), а можно запустить Ruby с ключом `--disable-gems` и получить оригинальный `require` на своём месте. Но это *очень* редко нужно.

На код `require` из RubyGems можно запросто взглянуть, поставив [Pry REPL](http://pryrepl.org/) и сделав в нём:

```
show-source require
# ИЛИ
$ require # то же самое, но короче
```